# Upload large excel file through my Google app engine application in to bigquery

Tags: java, excel, google-app-engine, apache-poi, google-bigquery

I want to upload large excel file through my Google app engine application in to Bigquery. Now I upload the data and read it using POI and then insert data in to Bigquery through streaming insertion. Which is not possible if I use this for larger excel file, which will definitely take more than 60 seconds(DeadlineExceededexception). Please suggest the right approach to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you hit DeadlineExceededexception for appengine requests, it usually is a sign that you will need to split the work done during that request.

If i have understood well your use case, you could:

1) Split it in steps: Upload, transform data, insert into BigQuery.

2) If a lot of data must be sent from client, use the [Blobstore Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/).

3) Use [Task Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) for other time consuming work. Note that they also have a deadline which is 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is even if you use taskqueue you need to pass the excel file which may be above 100 MB or may be quite larger. Is it possible to pass that through request object?